# Overflow hidden not working for "vertical aligned bottom" - divs in an absolute positioned outer div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem regarding my divs, which are vertical aligned to the bottom of a div.

My goal is to create a "log window", where I can display messages from bottom to the top. If there is not enough space, the top messages should fade away (overflow hidden).

Problems:

First, the height is not considered, if I put more divs inside, the container will grow and overtop 100px, as you can see in the example on jsfiddle (currently 116px).
Second, If I force it to 100px, it will cut the bottom div's instead of the top ones. I want to see the newest messages on the bottom (7, 6, 5, ...),

The outer div with position absolute needs to stay.

I've created a jsfiddle for better understanding:

https://jsfiddle.net/vbdo9xun/4/

```css
#notifications {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  z-index: 100000000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#notifications .content {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  background-color: #321d12;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#notifications .content div {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #efb718;
}
```

```html
<div id="notifications">
  <div class="content">
    <div>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur!</div>
    <div>2. tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna!</div>
    <div>3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy invidunt ut!</div>
    <div>4. sit amet, consetetur!</div>
    <div>5. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna!</div>
    <div>6. Lorem tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore!</div>
    <div>7. Amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could like this, using `position: absolute` on the `content` as well, starting out from the bottom

```css
#notifications {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 1px;
  top: 4px;
  height: 100px;          /* set height here instead */
  overflow: hidden;
}

#notifications .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  background-color: #404040;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#notifications .content div {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="notifications">
  <div class="content">
    <div>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur!</div>
    <div>2. tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna!</div>
    <div>3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy invidunt ut!</div>
    <div>4. sit amet, consetetur!</div>
    <div>5. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna!</div>
    <div>6. Lorem tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore!</div>
    <div>7. Amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is exactly what i was looking for. I tried the same, but somehow the div's werent stacked. But it works with your solution!